# Image not showing no matter what(Picasso,Glide,Async)

Tags: java, android

No matter what I do,the picture just doesn't want to show.

I have done the simplest code just for the test and I can really use some help.

I am getting no errors and no crashes,so I have no clue what to do.

I tried to use Glide and Asynce also but with no success.

btw,I added user permission on android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImageView);
        Picasso.get().load("https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg").into(myImage);
    }
}
```

ImageView Code:

```
ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mImageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

ImageView :

https://ibb.co/gwbfgWR

**THE EMULATOR IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!**

Can't believe,I feel so noob haha

Comment: network permissions? typo in permission name? permissions at wrong place?

Comment: Allowed it already.. 
Thanks for reply

Comment: please show the code for image view in your layout

Comment: myImage  is null? *`R.id.mImageView`* why it has so strange id ? (i'm pretty sure that large letters are not allowed)

Comment: I Think You Have To Add Some Height And Width To Show ImageView

Comment: @nvr,added to the post,thanks

Comment: @Selvin , myImage is the name of the new ImageView.
The id of the ImageView is mImageView

Comment: @JaYKuMaR added the ImageView on the screen.it has space to be shown..

Comment: try to set android:layout_height="wrap_content"
and adjustviewbounds=true

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys so I spent few hours trying to figure out what was the problem.

****THE EMULATOR IS THE PROBLEM!!!!!****

I tried the app on my phone and it works!

Next time I definitely going to use my phone as default.

Thanks for all the replayers!!

Comment: `https://imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg` On emulator use `https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("https://i.imgur.com/tGbaZCY.jpg")
                .into(myImage);

    }
}
```

ADD this

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
```

In Your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I did EXACLY as you wrote and it still doesn't work........

I get NO errors....

Comment: Try on an actual phone not on emulator